# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. visual basic vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, genetic-algorithm

```
Public Class Population

 Dim tours() As Tour    ' Tour is a class and I have to make and object array

 Public Sub New(ByVal populationSize As Integer, ByVal initialise As Boolean)

    Dim tours As New Tour(populationSize)   ' 

    If initialise Then
        ' Loop and create individuals
        For i As Integer = 0 To (populationSize - 1)
            Dim newTour As New Tour()
            newTour.generateIndividual()
            saveTour(i, newTour)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub saveTour(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal tour As Tour)
    tours(index) = tour           ' getting error in this line 
End Sub
```

same code in java is in [this link](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/applying-a-genetic-algorithm-to-the-travelling-salesman-problem/5)

Comment: Note that the size of your array will be populationSize + 1 because in VB the value passed in the array declaration is the upper bound, not the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while that I've done VB but I think your `DIM`-statement in the `New`-method creates a new local variable `tours` that hides the global variable `tours`.

Try this:

```
Public Class Population

 Dim tours() As Tour

 Public Sub New(ByVal populationSize As Integer, ByVal initialise As Boolean)

    tours = New Tour(populationSize)   ' 

    If initialise Then
        ' Loop and create individuals
        For i As Integer = 0 To (populationSize - 1)
            Dim newTour As New Tour()
            newTour.generateIndividual()
            saveTour(i, newTour)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub saveTour(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal tour As Tour)
    tours(index) = tour 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Public Sub New(ByVal populationSize As Integer, ByVal initialise As Boolean)

    ReDim tours(populationSize)

    If initialise Then
        ' Loop and create individuals
        For i As Integer = 0 To (populationSize - 1)
            Dim newTour As New Tour()
            newTour.generateIndividual()
            saveTour(i, newTour)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```